# How to use Guava ServiceManager with Guice Injection

Tags: java, guice, guava

As mentioned [here](https://plus.google.com/118010414872916542489/posts/86dUfeQk5dH), Guava ServiceManager can be obtained by

```
ServiceManager manager = injector.getInstance(ServiceManager.class);
```

To make this work, I added the following in my Guice module:

```
@Provides
public Set<Service> services(){
    return ImmutableSet.<Service>of(MyService());
}
```

In my main class,

```
ServiceManager manager = injector.getInstance(ServiceManager.class);
manager.startAsync().awaitHealthy();
```

How do I get instances of the started services?

p.s. Setting the services to be @Singleton feels like a hack.

Comment: I think I had the same question, but under another form. Instead of services I managed plugins. Basically, it involved Multibinder and private modules. I got it answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625837/generalize-guices-robot-legs-example-with-multibinding

Comment: hi @tanyehzheng is it a web application or a desktop one?

Comment: Although I was trying on a desktop application, my question is not specific to whether it's a desktop application or a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, setting the services to be `@Singleton` isn't a hack at all. That's probably what I'd do.

```
@Provides @Singleton
public MyService myService() {
  return new MyService();
}

@Provides
public Set<Service> services(MyService myService) {
  return ImmutableSet.<Service>of(myService);
}
```

Then you can just inject any particular service instance you want anywhere you want.

Comment: If that's the intended way of using it, I think they should make it clear because it's easy to make mistake of forgetting to annotate as @Singleton and end up getting a new unstarted service instance. It's pretty hard to debug this kind of issue.

Comment: is it guice is also a service at the ServiceManager?

Answer (score 2):

`ServiceManager.getServicesByState().get(RUNNING)` returns the running services and `ServiceManager.getServicesByState().values()` returns all of the services managed by the ServiceManager.